# Rails redirect to page user wanted to view prior to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to redirect users back to a page that they were trying to access prior to logging in (the page is only viewable to users).

I'll start off with a before filter that targets my trip new action:

`before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

```
def authenticate
  deny_access unless signed_in?
end 

def deny_access
  store_location
  redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Please log in to access this page."
end

def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end
```

Here is the new and create actions in my sessions_controller.rb

```
def new
  @title = "Log in"
end

def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email].downcase, 
                           params[:session][:password])     
  if user.nil?
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
    @title = "Log in"
    render 'new'
  else
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or(root_path)
  end
end

def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  clear_return_to
end
```

Thanks!

Edit: Removed MaddHacker's version of my code as that is not what I want.

Comment: Solved the problem. I just have to add `store_location` inside my controller right before I redirect to a login page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use a before_filter like

```
def login_required
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
  redirect_to(login_page_url)
end
```

Then when my login completes, I look for the return_to in the session:

```
def login
  # user validation of login here
  url = session[:return_to] || root_path
  session[:return_to] = nil
  url = root_path if url.eql?('/logout')
  logger.debug "URL to redirect to: #{url}"
  redirect_to(url)
end
```

Comment: I've tried using your code; however, I'm still getting redirected back to root_path so it looks like my session[:return_to] isn't storing the fullpath. I've added my version of your code to my post.

Comment: Also, this way only stores the session after I've logged in.

Comment: Try adding that logger.debug statement to see where you're going (I would also recommend checking against the logout url, as I had some problems when clicking logout, then trying to login again).  Just as a note, I would suggest that you store only the user's email address in the session (security thing) and just key the login off of that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first you need to call the store_return_to method before redirecting from the unauthorised page to the login page. Then I think you need to change the method description to something like `def redirect_back_or_default(default = root_path)` so the argument becomes optional.

By the way, Ican't realy understand why do you need to pass an argument to that method, if it is only a default value, wich you can hardcode in the method itself.

Comment: I tried calling the store_return_to method before redirecting to login page, but I still get redirected to my default path. Code added to original post.