# how to redirect to the previous page or action after successful login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

i have my own authentication set up i.e not using a gem like devise or others and its working well.
i have a before filter method

```
 def authenticate_user!
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Please Login" if current_user.nil?

  end
```

that is placed above some controllers to allow a login first before they can continue.
what i intend doing is that i want after a successful login, i want the user to be redirected to the previouse action instead of the root_url
my session controller that controls the login is bellow

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if params[:remember_me]
        cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      else
        cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      end
       redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539197/rails-redirect-to-page-user-wanted-to-view-prior-to-login?rq=1

Comment: thanks MrYoshiji it solved my problem....